# Laravel 5: "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"?

Tags: laravel, composer, laravelcollective

Estoy intentando instalar laravelcollective para mi proyecto (local, Windows 10, Laragon, Apache 2.4.35), pero me devuelve ese error y no me deja continuar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo, la versión que intentas instalar de laravelcollective/html no es compatible con tu versión de laravel, por que no intentas instalar esta versión de laravelcollective `composer require laravelcollective/html:5.8`

Comment: Correcto. Gracias!